# Unix command to create file:/// URI based on the file's directory (pwd)

Tags: linux, git, unix, command-line, cygwin

I would like to write a filepath as a URI in a Unix command-line emulator.

Desired output:

```
file:///C|/directory/filename.ext
```

Using sed and pwd I can get close but not quite there because

```
$ pwd
/c/directory/
```

...gives me a lower-case drive and no pipe.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `sed`; it has a `y` command to do the case-conversion, though it is somewhat convoluted because you would have to go through the hold space as well as the pattern space.  It would be easier to use Perl - it probably has one or more modules to do this (such as [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) and [URI::file](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI%3a%3afile)), though a simple version could be produced with regular expressions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
foreach my $name (@ARGV)
{
     if ($name =~ m%^/([a-zA-Z])(/.+)%)
     {
         printf "file:///%c|%s\n", uc($1), $2;
     }
     else
     {
         print STDERR "$0: unexpected name format - no /x/ drive letter prefix ($name)\n";
     }
 }
```

(Untested code.)